# Problem using scroll-snap css with javascript onScroll. They seem to cancel one another out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to identify when user is scrolling on my website. I think the javascript I'm running is having conflicts with the scroll-snap-type

I've tried playing around with the container height. If i make the height 100%, the javascript works, but the scroll snap does not.

code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/raylthomas/kw6bn2a8/2/

```
window.onscroll = ()=> console.log("Scrolling...");
```

Answer (score 1):

The conflict is due to the "overflow" rule, which is necessary for scroll-snap.  My solution is to check for mousewheel activity by using `window.onwheel()`